# Frobenius twist on a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be of characteristic $p$ and algebraically closed. Suppose $X=X'=\mathbb{A}^1$ as topological space. Define the regular functions on $X$ as usual ($X$ is the same as $\mathbb{A}^1$, not just topologically, but as a space with functions).
Let $U'(=U)$ be an open subset on $X'$. We say $f\in k[U']$ is regular if $f(x)=\phi(x)^p$ for some $\phi\in k[U]$.

I encountered a question in my studies regarding this map (Frobenius twist):

> Describe the intersection point between the graph of $\mathrm{Fr}:\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^1$ with the digonal and check that each one has multiplicity one.

This confuses me! First of all if intersection points are supposed to make sense then we are treating $X$ and $X'$ the same (forgetting about their ring of regular functions), otherwise the graph is a subset of $X\times X'$, while the diagonal is a subset of $X\times X$. The varieties $X\times X$ and $X\times X'$ also have different topologies (due to different regular function structures of $X$ and $X'$), although $X$ is the same as $X'$. But then if we are treating $X$ and $X'$ the same, the diagonal and the graph(Fr) are exactly the same (as a continuous Fr is just identity.) Now if they are the same the multiplicity is meaningless. I can't seem to be able make sense of this question.

Comment: It's not true that Frobenius is the identity here; for example, take $k = \mathbb{F}_p(x)$ or $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. And I have no idea what the significance of $X'$ is here.

Comment: Oh sorry, $k$ is also algebraically closed, forgot to say. I've never saw this map before, and the question defines it as identity (topologically). The exact wording is  "the identity map $X\to X'$ defines a morphism $\mathrm{Fr}: X\to X'$". The question has a lot of parts, I solved them all. This is the last part.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan They're basically just being asked to note that $\Gamma_{\mathrm{Frob}}\cdot \Delta$ is the set of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points of $X$ (at least in the case that $\overline{k}=\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$), and that the intersection is trivial since the derivative of $x-\mathrm{Frob}$ is the identity. This is just confusingly worded. Where is this from OP?

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is part of my homework for a grad course in alg. geo. at MIT. By the way, do you know anywhere I can read more about this map? seems interesting.